# How do you create a subscription in paypal that renews on specific yearly dates

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have a business case where i need to bill the user for a subscription on a yearly basis but starting at a specific date: 1 of april of current or previous year.

Examples:

- User registers on March 31st, 2015, gets charged 10$, gets charged 10$ again on the 1st of april 2015 and on each subsequent 1st of april
- User registers on 1st of may 2015, gets charged 10$, gets billed again on 1st of april 2016 and each 1st of april after that

Can this be done with paypal recurring payments profiles? I don't see anything regarding this in the doc although i do see that i cannot start a recurring profile in the past:

> The profile start date may not be earlier than the profile creation date.
>
> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/

Can this be done?

Comment: After relooking at the doc again (for the 4th time) i think i could use INITAMT to setup the initial fee of 10$ and then start the profile on the next 1st of april for 10$ yearly fee, can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Yes, use the initial amount. I have a donation system that will set up monthly deductions, we always do something like "$10 today, $10 a month starting ______". Another advantage of the initial amount is that you immediately determine if the card is valid. Without an initial amount, Paypal will establish a profile for any card that *looks* valid, and you don't find out if the charge will actually clear until later. When the scheduled payment is attempted, if it fails, it does not tell you **why** it failed. That initial amount will give you immediate feedback on the validity of the card.

Comment: Thanks, do an answer and i'll mark it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `INITAMT` field to indicate an immediate charge **in addition** to the profile charges.

Your values will look something like this, using NVP with `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`

```
'BILLINGPERIOD'=>'YEAR', // bill on a yearly basis
'BILLINGFREQUENCY'=>1, // bill once ever year
'TOTALBILLINGCYCLES'=>0, // how many periods (in this case, years) 0 = no end
'INITAMT'=>10, // charge this amount right now
'AMT'=>10, // amount to be billed each time
'FAILEDINITAMTACTION'=>'CancelOnFailure', // if the init amount fails, do not create a profile
'PROFILESTARTDATE'=>'2015-04-01T00:00:00Z' // April 1, 2015 -- adjust as needed
```

... you also need the standard fields like the first name, last name, and card details.

Charging an initial amount has a big advantage -- you get to verify the card right away. Without an initial amount, paypal will establish the recurring payment profile without actually touching the card, as long as all the information is there. It does not make sure the information is *right*. So, you could be setting up a profile for a card that doesn't actually work. You won't find out about the failure until the first profile billing, and then, you don't get any information about **why** it failed, just the fact that it did. With `INITAMT`, you get the detailed feedback you get for a normal one-time charge, eg. the card was declined, the CVV was wrong, etc.

Be sure to carefully explain the bill dates to your user. If this is happening on 3/29/2015, you might not want to do the first billing on 4/1/2015, but wait a month. This really depends on your use-case.

**Documentation**

- `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Thanks, the explanation is already in the business case and the templates are very clear about that!

Comment: As I understand, the first payment for the recurring profile (except the initial)  - gets taken on the start date of the profile?